# How to change tuples as elements in lists?

Tags: python, tkinter

I ran to a problem. I saw that tuples can't change, the only way is to convert them to a list and then convert them back. But, I got tuples as elements in a list. Here is part of the code:

```
while i<=5:
        r=random.randint(1,3)
        if r==1:
            a=list(timovi[i][0])+3
        if r==2:
            a=list(timovi[i][0])+1
            b=list(timovi[-i][0])+1
        if r==3:
            a=list(timovi[-i][0])+3
        i=i+1
```

I'm trying to make football/soccer league, so one value in tuple is points and other is team name. I need to change points. I tried to make variable representing list index number 1(points), but again I can't change the tuple. Can somebody help?

Comment: Append all the labels to a list. Then you can loop over the list to destroy them all.

Comment: Why do you use tuples in the first place? If you want to a mutable data structure, use list instead.